# How to compress data dimension

Tags: statistics

I have n points on the plane $(x_1, y_1) \ldots (x_n, y_n)$ - it's the points of one stroke. I want to reduce number of points without significant information loss.
I read some information about PCA, but I don't sure if it's what I need.

Can anyone recommend     methods for doing what I want.

Comment: If by "stroke" you mean the points are positioned along some curve then this sounds like the [Ramer–Douglas–Peucker algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ramer–Douglas–Peucker_algorithm)

Comment: @WimC, thanks a lot)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can model it as a function $y=f(x)$, trying various functions to find one you like.  The simplest is to fit the best straight line through your points.  You can use many functional forms, usually being guided by looking at your data.  Any numerical analysis text can help you.